# Setting the value of an object's boolean in a list to true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

So I have this class that allows me to check if a color has been selected or not:

```
public class Colors
{
    public bool mIsSelected { get; set; }
    public string mName { get; set; }
}
```

Before sending the list to the view, I populate it with these values:

```
public List<Colors> mListColors = new List<Colors>();

mListColors.Add(new Colors{ mIsSelected = false, mName = "black"});
mListColors.Add(new Colors { mIsSelected = false, mName = "blue" });
mListColors.Add(new Colors { mIsSelected = false, mName = "white" });
mListColors.Add(new Colors { mIsSelected = false, mName = "red" });
mListColors.Add(new Colors { mIsSelected = false, mName = "green" });
```

And in my view I render them like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.mListColors.Count; i++)
{
    var item = Model.mListColors[i];

switch (item.mName)
{
    case "black":
        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\blackColor.jpeg", item.mName.ToUpper(), null)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mIsSelected, item.mIsSelected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListColors[i].mName)
        break;
    case "blue":
        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\blueColor.jpeg", item.mName.ToUpper(), null)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mIsSelected, item.mIsSelected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListColors[i].mName)
        break;
    case "red":
        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\redColor.jpeg", item.mName.ToUpper(), null)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mIsSelected, item.mIsSelected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListColors[i].mName)
        break;
    case "green":
        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\greenColor.jpeg", item.mName.ToUpper(), null)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mIsSelected, item.mIsSelected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListColors[i].mName)
        break;
    case "white":
        @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\whiteColor.jpeg", item.mName.ToUpper(), null)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mIsSelected, item.mIsSelected)
        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mListColors[i].mName)
        break;
}
```

}

So that I may have a checkbox and set the value to true or false depending on wether if the checkbox is checked or not. The HtmlImage is a custom helper that allows me to display an image.

But the value in the controller is always false despite the box being checked or not, so what could I do to correct that?

Comment: Is there any code where a checkbox changes the dictionary's value?

Comment: Hum, well, I thought that the rendered view would take care of that, no? Ain't that the purpose of a `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper?

Comment: You specifically assigned the value of `mBlackColor` `mBlueColor` to `false`.  I don't see any code where its not set ot `false`

Comment: You really do not need that switch in there. You can remove a lot of code that way. Also where are you checking when you say "value in the controller is always false"?

Comment: Good point about the switch, I'm just trying to make things work. And I check in my controller, in my postback method I get the model which contains the `List<Colors>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off, you are setting them all to false. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx):

```
// Assign the result of a boolean expression to b.
b = (days % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: Well, I need to set them to false at start, because in another view if I did not proceed this way it would crash. Or is it useless? And I'm not sure why are you using a modulo to set them?

Comment: The modulo is just an example taken from the Microsoft link. You are using `a = b = c`, when it should be `a = (b == c)`. But if your intention was to initially set them all to false I misread and apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what Jason Evans suggests you can also refactor your code so your not violating DRY

```
@for(int idx = 0;idx < Model.ListColors.Count;idx++)
{
    var item = Model.ListColors[idx]
    @Html.Image(string.Format(
           "~\\Images\\Functional\\{0}Color.jpeg",
           item.Name.ToLower()), item.Name, null)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[idx].IsSelected, item.IsSelected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[idk].Name)
}
```

**Update**

You may want to consider creating a model that more accuratly reflects your data:

```
public class Colors
{
    public bool IsSelected {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And expose your model as:

```
@model IEnumerable<Colors>
```

Comment: Still, I cannot access to `Model.ListColors[idx]` because my dictionary is a string and not an int. Seems like a `for` loop cannot iterate through a `Dictionary<string, bool>`?

Comment: Perhaps you can change your model so it more reflects the data your working with and then expose it as a list instead of dictionary.

Comment: Well, its true that I could only focus on the colors and check if that color in the model is named that way. Sound advice, I will try this approach.

Comment: But another problem lies ahead. I will need to check if more than 1 item is checked to apply a certain behavior, and I don't know how to do that. This was why I created a dictionary at the start, so that I could check this possibility.

Comment: Iterate through the dictionary like this:       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> pair in myDictionary)
      {
        //...
      }

Comment: See updates. If you expose both `IsSelected` and `Name` (through a hidden field, that will allow the model binder to recreate your collection when it gets posted to your controller.

Comment: It does not work, I will update my code above to display what I have done up to now.

Comment: Post updated, tell me what you think of it or if I miss any parts

Comment: @Herve the only problem I see is when using the `HTML` helper methods to create fields you have to use the model directly (`@Html.HiddenFor(_item => Model.mListColors[i].mName)`)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm wrong again, please downvote, but shouldn't it be with `Value`?

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => color.Value, Model.mListColors["Blue"].Value)`

Comment: No downvote from me, but I have tried this approach and this does not change a thing. I'm trying Jay's method right now.